# Как в Pandas получить значения столбца из мульти-индекса сводной таблицы?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, multi-index

Есть сводная таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно получить столбец "OUT" (часть индекса) как значения для дальнейшей передачи в нейронку скажем.

```
df_norm_.index
```

дает мультииндекc, но как из него взять второй столбец - ума не приложу.

```
df_norm_.index[1]
```

дает пару индексов с номером 1: (390, 1). А
 обращение

```
df_norm_.index["OUT"]
```

выдает ошибку... 
Я конечно могу выкрутить руки так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
но почему-то это не дает правильного ответа тоже...
Ведь на предыдущем слайде подряд 8 единиц... а здесь на пятом месте уже ноль...

Comment: а что, `df["OUT"].values` не решит проблемы?

Comment: @strawdog  -  KeyErorr
в сводной таблице нет столбца "OUT"  -  это часть индекса

Comment: @VasylKolomiets это не подойдет https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html ?

Comment: @Andrey, если вы оформите ваш комментарий как ответ - я удалю вариант с `df.index.get_level_values(1)` из своего ответа...

Comment: @MaxU все ок, не удаляйте. Я не буду оформлять отдельным ответом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исходный DF:

```
In [203]: df
Out[203]:
                     0         1         2         3
first second
bar   one     0.205973 -0.403744 -0.716060  0.449733
      two    -1.074096  1.341120 -0.216712  0.957400
baz   one    -0.553551 -0.624259 -1.241866  2.492807
      two     1.335034 -0.456473  1.500064  1.526427
foo   one     0.173070  0.567775 -0.222740  0.030894
      two    -0.043697  0.536522 -1.814972 -0.188887
qux   one     0.269183 -1.868055  1.344501 -0.506121
      two     0.498302 -0.306272 -0.293913  1.550167
```

---

Наиболее идиоматичный вариант уже [указал @Andrey в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/964064/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-pandas-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%86-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9#comment1614714_964064):

```
In [204]: df.index.get_level_values(1)
Out[204]: Index(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'], dtype='object', name='second')
```

Вариант 1 с `.reset_index(level=<index_level_number>)`:

```
In [205]: df.reset_index(level=1)['second'].values
Out[205]: array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'], dtype=object)
```

Вариант 2 с `.reset_index(level=<index_level_name>)`:

```
In [206]: df.reset_index(level='second')['second'].values
Out[206]: array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'], dtype=object)
```

---

Данные для создания исходного игрушечного DF:

```html
df = pd.DataFrame(
{0: {('bar', 'one'): 0.20597346900510116,
  ('bar', 'two'): -1.0740962720471594,
  ('baz', 'one'): -0.5535505995153884,
  ('baz', 'two'): 1.3350343617931544,
  ('foo', 'one'): 0.1730697501809625,
  ('foo', 'two'): -0.043697458626714,
  ('qux', 'one'): 0.2691829986873178,
  ('qux', 'two'): 0.4983017887971038},
 1: {('bar', 'one'): -0.4037441703092006,
  ('bar', 'two'): 1.3411199938414102,
  ('baz', 'one'): -0.6242586374458912,
  ('baz', 'two'): -0.45647251856573634,
  ('foo', 'one'): 0.5677751470294398,
  ('foo', 'two'): 0.5365220610310172,
  ('qux', 'one'): -1.8680546696869031,
  ('qux', 'two'): -0.3062719539989547},
 2: {('bar', 'one'): -0.7160603640668033,
  ('bar', 'two'): -0.2167120301102546,
  ('baz', 'one'): -1.2418655822812408,
  ('baz', 'two'): 1.5000638406131677,
  ('foo', 'one'): -0.22274008778504206,
  ('foo', 'two'): -1.8149720525211626,
  ('qux', 'one'): 1.3445013025101284,
  ('qux', 'two'): -0.2939133657145476},
 3: {('bar', 'one'): 0.4497325390675965,
  ('bar', 'two'): 0.957399653216663,
  ('baz', 'one'): 2.492807277698116,
  ('baz', 'two'): 1.5264272939729429,
  ('foo', 'one'): 0.030894287007498675,
  ('foo', 'two'): -0.18888706751843662,
  ('qux', 'one'): -0.5061207998701763,
  ('qux', 'two'): 1.5501666900299136}})
```